# Поиск документов, значение ключа у которых не выходит за рамки полученного массива

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-query

Мне нужно получить массив от пользователя и сделать выборку из базы по следующему принципу:
если полученный массив такой

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'penguin']
```

то мне нужны документы где

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'penguin']
animals = ['cat', 'dog']
animals = ['cat' 'penguin']
и т.д.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вообще называются такие выборки и как их правильно делать в mongodb.

Comment: Вроде [это?][1]

[1]: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

Comment: @alvoro, нет. допустим, у нас есть документы
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'penguin', 'cockroach']
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'penguin']
animals = ['cat', 'dog']
animals = ['penguin']

если мы подадим на поиск 
['cat', 'dog', 'penguin'] 
то что запрос с $all, что запрос с $in вернет нам 
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'penguin', 'cockroach']
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'penguin']

а нужно как раз
animals = ['cat', 'dog']
animals = ['penguin']

Comment: @alvoro, совершенно верно. 
нашел вот здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/134590/#comment_4470201 как можно передавать функцию. буду пробовать с ее помощью, но это, наверное, не самый красивый способ.

Comment: Тоже через $where хотел предложить. А чем этот способ не красивый?

Comment: @alvoro, у меня сервер на питоне и стандартные функции монги работают быстрее (при условии использования драйвера, написанном на си), чем питонические. ничего критичного в этом нет, просто заиграло во мне что-то, стремящиеся к идеалу :)

Comment: Не знаю поможет это или нет, но в mongodb можно [сохранить функцию][1]. Что это и с чем его едят я, честно говоря, пока только догадаюсь, но возможно это то, что вам надо.

[1]: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=mongodb+%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8&oq=mongodb+%D1%85%D1%80&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l5j0i22i30l4.27916.29858.0.30743.5.4.1.0.0.0.126.394.2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..0.5.401.TrSYZ6RAO1c

Comment: @alvoro, ну там с оптимизациями уже разберусь, главное, что выяснили про $where. если вас интересуют очки, можете все что мы здесь насобирали, написать в полноценный ответ, а я вам скажу спасибо поднятием пальца вверх и меткой решения. а если нет, то просто человеческое вам спасибо!

Comment: @fogipoziw Ну вы меня прям лайко"нехорошее слово" выставили. Оно, конечно, льстит когда плюсуют, но это не главное. Человеческого спасибо будет предостаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Если запрос достаточно сложный, и базовых средств либо знаний не хватает, то всегда можно воспользоваться механизмом `$where`. То есть можно написать сложную логику получения данных, включая *if-ы*, и вернуть результат, чего в обычных базах данных добиться очень и очень сложно (имею в виду условия и циклы внутри *SQL-запросов*).

Синтаксис прост — в качестве параметра передаётся функция:

```
db.foo.find({$where : функция})
```

При этом используется объект (переменная) `this`, по сути — курсор, у которой можно получать свойства.
Функция должна вернуть `true` или `false`, что означает, попадёт строка в выборку или нет.
Вот пример из википедии:

```
db.foo.find({$where : function() { return this.x == this.y; }})
```

При этом также можно использовать вложенные `OR` или `AND`, как в классических `SQL-запросах`:

```
db.foo.find({$where : function() { 
  if((this.cost>5 && this.cost<10 )|| (this.is_hidden != 1) || (this.link == this.url)){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}})
```

Таким образом, курсор пробегает по базе, и выполняет проверки. разумеется, всё это можно ограничивать лимитами на количество строк, $where — всего лишь ключ в массиве параметров запроса.

Необходимо понимать, что это всё-таки медленне, чем обычные запросы, но всё равно достаточно быстро.

---

скопировано [отсюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/134590/#comment_4470201) по наводке из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/317059#comment317093_317059) автора вопроса.

Comment: здесь  не нужно использовать `$where` оператор. нужно агрегация.

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, у вас есть следующие документы в вашей коллекции.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b809f"),
        "animals" : [
                "rat",
                "cat"
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a0"),
        "animals" : [
                "dog",
                "cat",
                "penguin"
        ]
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a1"), "animals" : [ "dog" ] },
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a2"),
        "animals" : [
                "cat",
                "dog"
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a3"),
        "animals" : [
                "dog",
                "penguin"
        ]
}
```

и массив "animals":

```
var animals = [ "cat", "dog", "penguin" ];
```

Лучший способ это делать это используя [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) метод который обеспечивает доступ к агрегации цепочке. Первый этап в цепочке это [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) где вы отфильтроваете документы, которые не имеют какой-либо элемента в массиве "animals". Это также уменьшает количество документов, которые будут обрабатываться в следующей стадии.

Следующий и последний этап — это [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact). Здесь нужно использовать оператор [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) точно делает что мы хотим; он возврашает `true`  если все элементы первого множество появляются во втором множество, в том числе, когда первый множеств равен второй; и также потому MongoDB не позволяет использовать `$in`  в [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond). Конечно [`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) и [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) являются системные переменные.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "animals": { "$in": animals } } }, 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$setIsSubset": [ "$animals", animals ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] 
    }} 
])
```

Это запрос возврашает следующий результат:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a0"),
        "animals" : [
                "dog",
                "cat",
                "penguin"
        ]
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a1"), "animals" : [ "dog" ] }
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a2"),
        "animals" : [
                "cat",
                "dog"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ac7281ebc094e3677b80a3"),
        "animals" : [
                "dog",
                "penguin"
        ]
}
```

Здесь вам не нужно использовать оператор [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) поскольку он [вызовет падение производительности.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations)

> - $where evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes. Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., $gt, $in).
> - In general, you should use $where only when you can’t express your query using another operator. If you must use $where, try to include at least one other standard query operator to filter the result set. Using $where alone requires a table scan.

Конечно `$redact` не использует индексы. Он даже делает сканирования все документы в коллекции но более лучше.